# zeep - disable warning "Forcing soap:address location to HTTPS"

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, wsdl, zeep

I'm using the `zeep` package to access some API on https, and on every connection it prints out a warning (to stderr):

```
Forcing soap:address location to HTTPS
```

Some searching I did turned up that the line responsible is [this](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/blob/master/src/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py#L218), which implies that this the result of the logging level of the module. Changing the log level seems to require editing [this file](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/transport.html#debugging).

This is a bad solution for me because I want to be able to turn this warning off at run time, because the app using this package will be a frozen app (an exe).

If that's relevant, these are the minimum lines required to display that warning (although obviously, the domain here is a fictional one, and so are the user and password):

```
import zeep
client = zeep.CachingClient('https://api.somedomain.com/Services/ApiService.svc?singleWsdl')
client.service.VerifyLogin('user', 'pass')
```

I know `zeep` clients can be set to not force https, but I assume that would make the connection less secure? (after all, I'm passing usernames and passwords as clear text without https)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be a bit more specific with log level switch, in order not to miss other warnings in zeep module as a whole, you could set it alternatively like this below:

```
logging.getLogger('zeep.wsdl.bindings.soap').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

That will prevent warning messages only for the soap binding class, but not for the rest.

Answer (score 8):

After a few days of research I've finally been able to solve this on my own. I didn't realize logging levels can be changed from imported modules. I added this line at the start of my code (after imports) and it fixed the issue:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('zeep').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Hope this helps other people that encounter the same problem

Answer (score 2):

How about the warnings context manager?

you can do something like this, which I've used in the past

```py
import zeep
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    warnings.simplefilter('always') 
    # this filters all warnings, and the context manager records them
    # your code is here:
    client = zeep.CachingClient('https://api.somedomain.com/Services/ApiService.svc?singleWsdl')
    client.service.VerifyLogin('user', 'pass')

    # now you want to verify you didn't ignore a different warning
    # here's an idea of how to verify:
    assert len(w) == 1, "More than one warning caught!"
    assert isinstance(w[0], WarningCategoryItShouldBe)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but sadly it doesn't work. I'm guessing this isn't really a warning being "raised" as much as it is a simple logging action